# Click Button on ListView is not working

Tags: c#, sql, .net, sql-server, visual-studio

I am an trying to get a click or double click to work on my listview, and my listview1_1 click doesn't seem to work. Whenever I click on a selected item, no messagebox pops up. I followed the usual format in creating a click event, however that does not seem to work. Is it because I am loading in the data from a database into the listview, instead of data that I created inside of the listview? Thanks so much!

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace sundayschoolproject
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
     {
    string con = ("Data Source=ZTABASSUM\\SQLEXPRESS01;Initial Catalog=   Sunday School;Integrated Security=True");
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        listView1.GridLines = true;
        listView1.View = View.Details;

        //Add Columns 
        listView1.Columns.Add("ParentName", 100);
        listView1.Columns.Add("Address", 150);
        listView1.Columns.Add("City", 100);
        listView1.Columns.Add("State", 50);
        listView1.Columns.Add("Zipcode", 100);
        listView1.Columns.Add("Phone", 150);


    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string sql = ("Select * from Family");
        SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(con);

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, connection);

        connection.Open();

        SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        listView1.Items.Clear();

        while (dr.Read())
        {
            ListViewItem lv = new ListViewItem(dr.GetString(0));
            lv.SubItems.Add(dr.GetString(1));
            lv.SubItems.Add(dr.GetString(2));
            lv.SubItems.Add(dr.GetString(3));
            lv.SubItems.Add(dr.GetString(4));
            lv.SubItems.Add(dr.GetString(5));
            listView1.Items.Add(lv);
        }


        dr.Close();
        connection.Close();



    }





        private void listView1_Click(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (listView1.SelectedItems.Count > 0)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("You clicked " + listView1.SelectedItems[0].Text);
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please select an item");
        }

    }

}
}
```

Comment: listview1_click. I tried debugging, but no error is popping up!

Comment: Yes there are, two based on what is selected within the if else statement.

Comment: listView1.SelectedItems.Count  is equal to zero before clicking

Comment: yes it seems to highlight and execute. However, the previous code  lv.SubItems.Add(dr.GetString(#)) has an invaldcastexception. Could this be the problem?

Comment: no i did not set the multiselect property. Should that solve the problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that you are trying to click on one of the `SubItems` that a `ListViewItem` has and nothing happens.

Well, to be able to make a SubItem clickable, you need first to make the `FullRowSelect` property of the ListView you have to allow the full row selection:

```
listView1.FullRowSelect = true;
```

then you can use [`ListView.HitTest`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w8ssfa8a.aspx) method that gives you information of an item that is located in a given point.

You could use the `ListView.HitTest` method in `MouseClick` or `MouseDoubleClick` rather than `Click` or `DoubleClick` events, because they provides an instance of  `MouseEventArgs` class that will help you to get the mouse location that you will use it in the `HitTest` method to locate the clicked subitem, try this:

```
private void listView1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    // Get the information of an item that is located in a given point (mouse location in this case).
    ListViewHitTestInfo hit = listView1.HitTest(e.Location);
    // hit.Item: Gets the ListViewItem.
    // hit.SubItem: Get the ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem

    if (listView1.SelectedItems.Count > 0)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("You clicked " + hit.SubItem.Text);
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Please select an item");
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried this, but my mouse click still does not work!

Comment: Are you sure that your `ListView` is not disabled?

Comment: I figured it out! I did not have an event handler in Form1.Designer.cs! rookie mistake!